# Remove all records that have duplicates based on more than one variables

Tags: r, duplicates

I have data like this

```r
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E"), var2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6 ))
#   var1 var2
# 1    A    1
# 2    A    2
# 3    B    3
# 4    B    4
# 5    C    5
# 6    D    5
# 7    E    6
```

`A` is mapped to `1, 2`

`B` is mapped to `3, 4`

`C` and `D` are both mapped to `5` (and vice versa: `5` is mapped to `C` and `D`)

`E` is **uniquely** mapped to `6` *and* `6` is **uniquely** mapped to `E`

I would like filter the dataset so that only

```
   var1 var2
7    E    6
```

is returned. `base` or tidyverse solution are welcomed.

I have tried

```
unique(df$var1, df$var2)
df[!duplicated(df),]
df %>% distinct(var1, var2)
```

but without the wanted result.

Comment: So you basically want to keep rows only if vars1 is unique and vars2 is unique?

Comment: yes but not in R's unique() sense. I want to have only the rows, the data of which exclusively map between var1 and var2

Comment: Interesting that there‘s no immediate tidyverse way. I thought about filter or distinct or count. But none of it works. Conceptually, it sounds easy, i.e. you first need to count each var, append the count for esch column to your data and then filter on those case where alle respective counts equal to 1. I thought I can easily add counts for all vars with add_count, but it doesn‘t work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `igraph::components`.

Represent data as graph and get connected components:

```r
library(igraph)
g = graph_from_data_frame(df)
cmp = components(g)
```

Grab components where cluster size (`csize`) is 2. Output vertices as a two-column character matrix:

```r
matrix(names(cmp$membership[cmp$membership %in% which(cmp$csize == 2)]),
       ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, names(df))) # wrap in as.data.frame if desired
#      var1 var2
# [1,] "E"  "6"
```

Alternatively, use names of relevant vertices to index original data frame:

```r
v = names(cmp$membership[cmp$membership %in% which(cmp$csize == 2)])
df[df$var1 %in% v[1:(length(v)/2)], ]
#   var1 var2
# 7    E    6
```

---

Visualize the connections:

```r
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: this is a very interesting solutions and aspect

Comment: this should also work for more that 2 variables right?

Comment: Then you have to create your graph differently. `graph_from_data_frame` assumes "A data frame containing a symbolic edge list in the first two columns". However, there are several `graph_from_` functions - pick one that suits your needs.

Comment: how can I have the results as a data frame (either a new dataframe conatining these kind of uniques) or asubsetting factor to subset the initial data frame. cmp$membership[cmp$membership %in% which(cmp$csize == 2)] seems to output a vector

Comment: @ECII Edit to provide output as a two-column matrix, just wrap in `as.data.frame` if desired.

Comment: nice `igraph` option, upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom function to determine if the mapping is unique you could achieve your desired result like so:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  var2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6)
)

is_unique <- function(x, y) ave(as.numeric(factor(x)), y, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)

df[is_unique(df$var2, df$var1) & is_unique(df$var1, df$var2), ]
#>   var1 var2
#> 7    E    6
```

Comment: this seems to do what I need, thank you very much. It is however limited to 2 variables. I am curious why I could not find anything already for such operation.

Comment: That's what you asked for. (; Maybe you could clarify your question and provide some example data including more than two variables.

Comment: @stefan That said, then I think OP rather may post a new question, so that current answers, including yours, (answering what is currently asked for) does not become invalidated. Cheers

Comment: @Henrik. Yep. I agree. That would be the preferred way. PS: Indeed an interesting answer using igraph tools. Have to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Another `igraph` option

```
decompose(graph_from_data_frame(df)) %>%
  subset(sapply(., vcount) == 2) %>%
  sapply(function(g) names(V(g)))
```

which gives

```
     [,1]
[1,] "E"
[2,] "6"
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution:

```
df[!(duplicated(df$var1) | duplicated(df$var1, fromLast = TRUE) | 
       duplicated(df$var2) | duplicated(df$var2, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
  var1 var2
7    E    6
```